# Should I use ui:fragment with the render attribute to conditionally render HTML tags in Facelets with JSF 2.2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, facelets, taglib

I am in the process of upgrading an old project from JSF 1.1 to JSF 2.2. Specifically, I am upgrading the JSF implementation from MyFaces 1.1 to MyFaces 2.2.12, replacing JSPs with Facelets and upgrading/replacing outdated tag libraries. I am mainly using [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0) as a guide.

The project used some tag library called `htmLib` with the namespace `http://jsftutorials.net/htmLib` in it's JSP pages. I can't find any documentation about this tag library anymore, neither on the jsftutorials webpage nor elsewhere, but apparently it was used to include plain HTML tags like `<div>` or `<table>` in JSP pages.

Since plain HTML tags can now be used in XML Facelets with JSF2, I am right now removing all occurences of tags from the `htmLib` taglib like `<htm:div>...</htm:div>` and replace them with plain HTML tags like `<div>...</div>`.

However, some of the tags used from `htmLib` contain the `render` attribute for conditional rendering, like this:

```
<htmLib:h4 render="someCondition">
   ...
</htmLib:h4>
```

Because plain HTML tags don't have a `render` attribute for this purpose, I was searching for an alternative way to conditionally render plain HTML tags and stumbled upon this answer on SO: [How to conditionally render plain HTML elements like <div>s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816212/how-to-conditionally-render-plain-html-elements-like-divs)

So, my idea is to replace a construct like the one above with something like

```
<ui:fragment render="someCondition">
   <h4>
      ...
   </h4>
</ui:fragment>
```

My questions:

- Is wrapping HTML tags inside a `<ui:fragment>` tag with the `render`
  attribute the recommended way to conditionally render HTML tags, or
  is this method only valid and recommended for the case in the linked question?
- Are there other ways to conditionally render plain HTML tags in Facelets that should be preferred?
- Does the `<ui:fragment>` wrapping method work, no matter what kind of plain HTML is contained within it?
- Can conditionally rendered `<ui:fragment>` blocks be nested?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's **no limitation** in that. Not even for wrapping `ui:fragment`.

Basically:

- In order just to control the inner content, with no extra HTML generation use
  `ui:fragment`.
- To generate an extra HTML `span` element, use `h:panelGroup`.
- To generate an extra HTML `div` element, use `h:panelGroup layout="block"`.

The HTML you have inside isn't a problem. JSF, being a server side framework, performs all the HTML building/rendering job in the server, so the JSF/facelet tags get translated to HTML before the response being sent. All the plain HTML you use inside will remain HTML.

**However**, beware of [using tag handlers inside UI Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394290/jsf-2-0-uiincludexhtml-included-always-even-if-rendered-is-false) when migrating from 1.x. Tag handlers (`ui:include`, `c:if`, `c:forEach`) evaluate **before** the UI Components (which tipically contain `rendered` clauses). This has been a source of conflict in JSF 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and explanation! So, do I understand correctly that if I have no tag handlers (`ui:include`, `c:if` etc.) inside the `ui:fragment` and don't need additional `<div>` or `<span>` elements, wrapping a `<ui:fragment rendered="...">` tag around my pure HTML content is indeed the way to go?

Comment: @scholt there's no problem with that!