# ui:include is not working inside p:dataGrid

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datagrid, facelets

I am trying to load dynamic xhtmls inside a datagrid. but somehow it displays correct data in p:outputlabel and got a null inside ui:include.

here is my code snippet

```
<p:dataGrid var="myBoard" value="#{dashBoard.widgetList}" columns="2"
                rows="2" paginator="true" id="widgetsGrid"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" 
                rendered="#{dashBoard.boardSize gt 0}">

        **// ***** Here is populate correct data ********
        <p:outputLabel value="#{myBoard.endpointUrl}" />  

        <p:panel id="one_#{myBoard.id}">
            <p:lightBox iframe="true" id="lighbox_one_#{myBoard.id}" height="550px" width="1024px" >
                <h:outputLink value="display" title="#{myBoard.name}">
                    <ui:insert name="widgetone">

                        **// ******* how come this would be null? *********

                        <ui:include src="#{myBoard.endpointUrl}"> 
                        </ui:include>

                    </ui:insert>
                    <f:param name="id" value="#{myBoard.id}" />
                </h:outputLink>
            </p:lightBox>
        </p:panel>      

    </p:dataGrid>
```

I did tried different ways to put it in `c:if` but couldn't resolve the same. 
is this sequence supported by primefaces or any suggestions to implement the same?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

That's because "#{myBoard.endpointUrl}" is null during the "Restore View Phase".

For more details about JSF Lifecycle : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSFIntro10.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply... so is there any workaround to achieve the same in p:dataGrid ? or i should use some other component ?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990965/jsf-uiinclude-not-being-rendered-properly